# Running an external program

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to run an external program with a VBScript in WinCC and I am almost there. The trick is, I want to make it more flexible, i.e. run the program independent from the default installation directory. I get into troubles since the folder consists white spaces and I can't seem to pass the path to the `Shell.Run` method. I'm getting the following error:

> Invalid procedure call or argument

What am I missing?

```
Dim shell  
Dim cmdRet

Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  

Set cmdRet = shell.Exec("cmd /c cd /d c:\ & dir vncviewer.exe /s /b")

shell.Run """" & cmdRet.StdOut.ReadLine & """" '"""C:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe""" 

Set cmdRet = Nothing
Set shell = Nothing
```

Comment: AFAICS the code -despite being ugly- should work. What do you get when you replace `shell.Run` with `WScript.Echo`?

Comment: I am getting "c:\Program Files\uvnc bvba\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe" (including the quotation marks), which is what I expect. The `shell.Run`  command gives me an error "Ungültiger Prozeduraufruf oder ungültiges Argument", which is "Invalid procedure call or argument". I am running this with WinCC as a script in one of the HMI elements.

Comment: Then the issue is with WinCC. The code works with the default interpreters.